# What happens when I disband my own guild?

Tags: castle-clash

If I disband my own guild to join a new guild what happens to my research/guild credits, flags, and so on?

Answer (score 3):

Once you disband your guild, everything with it disappears. All your research, guild credits, and flags will be forever gone.